# changing the typset of strings read into a google sheet

Tags: python, gspread

I'm relatively new to python, but is there a way to make the values one reads into their spreadsheet **bold**? I want to create headers that have a bold typeset, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Thank you!

Here is the statement I am trying to do this with. I want to make the strings in 'row' boldfaced when they read into my spreadsheet

```
#read in header values
row = ['Group ID','N. of Galaxies','Central RA','Central DEC','Central z','Group Span From Center (MPC/h)']
index = 1
#sheet.insert_row(row, index)
```

Comment: Katiya, I would advice you to include some code you have tried into your question, else, you might end with your question flagged and removed.

Comment: @acarlstein Thank you for letting me know! I've changed it above

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the line below.

```
sheet.format('A1:A6', {'textFormat': {'bold': True}})
```

And change the a1 notation to match the width of your header row.  That should do the trick!

More details at: https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#formatting